# Callback not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have a (asynchronous) function that gets the ID of a logged in user in Chrome. I'm trying to return the value of the ID with a callback but it keeps returning 'undefined'.

Before someone tries to mark this a duplicate, I used the code from here (and tried other places too): [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function) But it didn't work:

```
function getGaia(callback) {
    chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo){
      var userId = userInfo.id;
      callback(userInfo.id);
    });
}

getGaia(function(id){
    return id;
});

var gaiaId = getGaia();
```

I get the following error:

```
'callback' is a not a function
```

What exactly am I doing wrong / what is the correct code?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `callback` or `Callback`?  The error says you're capitalizing "Callback".  But your code has callback as lower case.

Comment: in error, 'Callback' is a not a function ,  here C is capital in callback

Comment: Edit has been made - It was a typo

Comment: You want `getGaia(function(id) { ... do something with the id here ... });`

Comment: You're executing getGaia without a callback function in last line.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are not providing a callback.

```js
function doSomethingLater(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}

console.log('This is before the callback');
doSomethingLater(function() {
  console.log('This is the callback')
});
```

So when you are calling `var gaiaId = getGaia();` you are not passing in a callback function

[Edit] This is what your code would need to look like:

```
function getGaia(callback) {
    chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo){
      var userId = userInfo.id;

      // This will call the function that you pass in below 
      //and pass in userInfo.if as a parameter
      callback(userInfo.id); 
    });
}

var gaiaId = getGaia(function (id) {
    // id === userInfo.id from above
    // Do something with the id that you pass in
});
```

You can think of functions like variables in JavaScript,

So you can assign a function to a variable like this:

`var foo = function () { ... }`

This means that you can pass this into functions like normal variables. When you pass the function in as a parameter, you are assigning the function to the name that you specify in the parameters:

```
var foo = function () { ... }

function hasCallback(callback) {
    // The following two line do exactly the same thing:
    callback(); // Using the function that you passed in
    foo(); // Using the function directly
}

hasCallback(foo);
```

All I have done above is, instead of creating the variable `foo` I just created the function inline:

```
var foo = function () { ... }

function hasCallback(callback) {
    // The following two line do exactly the same thing:
    callback(); // Using the function that you passed in
    foo(); // Using the function directly
}

hasCallback(foo);

// Becomes: 

function hasCallback(callback) {
    callback(); // Using the function that you passed in
}

hasCallback(function () { ... });
```

Comment: Basically, you have to set any variables and handle all logic related to the `Gaia` `ID` within the callback.

Comment: @JamesJameson2456 are you new to JavaScript?

Comment: @NicholasRobinson How do I call that function now?